# Outlook 2013 and exchange. Cant see new mail in subfolders

Tags: exchange, outlook

In our company we have exchange 2010 with sp3 and all clients with windows 8.1 and Outlook 2013. Problem is that clients have problem with new messages in their mailboxes. they cant see new messages in subfolders. In Outlook 2010 everything worked fine, and after migration to 2013 this problem started.

For example:

There is user mailbox. He have a lot of subfolders. All subfolders is for varies companies. So he created rules, then someone writes from  campany, mail goes to its subfolder. Problem is that then user opens Outlook in the morning, he can't see that new mails are arrived to those subfolders. User must open that subfolder and only then, inside that subfolder he can see unread message. But how user can know, that inside is unread mail? :) Sometimes everything works fine, and sometimes user can't see new mails. Then he opens OWA, all new mails is marked as unread and there is number near subfolder with unread mail count.

And this problem repeats to all users. I updated exchange to SP3 update 6. Operating system and Outlook is up to date. Recreation of profile helps for a week or two (Or user do not notice problem), and after that user calls me again with the same problem. And this happens not for one user but for all. Sometimes restarting Outlook helps, after restart number with unread mail count appears near subfolder. There is no addins or other changes in Outlook. Search folder is not a solution, because there is a lot of subfolders, so it would be a mess.

Can you advice me? Where can be problem? Is it global for all users who are using exchange 2010 and Outlook 2013?

Comment: You should take a screenshot to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Maybe a little late but uncheck Cached Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that's a bad was file to file email, but [it's not easy to control your users and their mail habits](https://serverfault.com/questions/303186/email-hoarder-intervention-and-education-exchange-environment)... Are these server-side rule or client-side rules? Does OWA work the way you want?

If anything, I believe the more elegant solution is to use a Search Folder. There should already be one for *Unread Mail*. If there's too much mail for that to work well, that points to a bigger issue.

[Is this what you're talking about?](https://superuser.com/q/67433/61194)

Comment: I think this is server side rules, because in owa everyfing works just as i want. All mail goes to folders by rules ant near folder is number with unread mail count.

Comment: I tryed using search folder but this solution didnt helped. Then user opens Outlook he sees unread mail count near subfolder, and sum of unread mails in search folder. But somefing happens and new mails does not appear neither in search folder neither near subfolders. But then client opens subfolder there are unread mails. In OWA everytime everything is OK. So user must check in OWA is there new mails and in which subfolder, then he opens that subfolder in Outlook, and uhnread mail is here.

Comment: And another thing. Now one of clients have this problem. There is no count of new mails in subfolders, outlook does not show it, but OWA shows. In rules, client created few rules, near rules in action section, there is icon, it looks like screwdriver and wrench, i went to propeties of those rules and removed "Stop processing more rules", and this icon disappeared. All rules updated to server, and after that, new messages counts appeared near few subfolders. Is it possible that somehow this message count is combined with rules? Ant what does whis screwdriver and wrench icon means?