# What limits should I put on user mailboxes?

Tags: exchange-2013

I have a server running Microsoft Exchange Server 2013.

I have noticed that the limits are all set to unlimited. Is this the default values on new installations or is this something that someone would have set at some point?

What are the default values on new installations, or what would be good suggested limits?

```
*Issue a warning at (GB): unlimited

*Prohibit send at (GB): unlimited

*Prohibit send and receive at (GB): unlimited
```

How can I view all mailboxes ordered by size?

Comment: You can see mailboxes sorted by size with: `Get-Mailbox| Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort-Object TotalItemSize | ft DisplayName, TotalItemSize, ItemCount`

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Why would/do you want to impose limits on your users? How would we know what limits you should set?

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you gave us (none) we can't give you an answer for what **you** should use. It usually comes down to what the company can afford. Here's some thoughts to help you figure this out.

It depends on the business needs; it really should not come down as an edict from the IT department. You may be short on storage today; you can suggest to the business that you should put in quotas. They may resist, in which case you present them with a proposal to buy more disk storage. They may sign off on that plan, or agree that quotas are a good idea.

Do you implement one quota, or multiple levels of quotas? The legal team, or marketing, or the president, may need a larger quota than a helpdesk technician or a receptionist, for example.

What quotas do you want to implement? Running some statistics on current mailbox sizes, and grouping my title or department, will give you some insight into current usage and could be the start of that discussion with management.

If you implement quotas, how will users react? Will some users automatically be over their assigned quota? You should plan some user education, in any event, and figure out what process (if any) a user can get a bigger quota than their initial assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is self-explanatory.

The mailbox quotas are described in detail in the users' mailbox dialog. The actions and behaviors are outlined.

[image]

These quotas can be set globally per database, but also overridden at the user level.

I only have a 100MB step between the soft and hard quota limits. Keep in mind that Microsoft Exchange sends [nightly reminder emails](http://sites.tufts.edu/tusmtss/files/2012/05/Your-Mailbox-is-almost-full.jpg) to users nearing their quotas.

[image]

In my environments, I size for the average user and deal with exceptions as needed. Examples may include a lawyer or compliance office on staff, or the owner, or the super-critical [*email-hoarding*](https://serverfault.com/questions/303186/email-hoarder-intervention-and-education-exchange-environment) "problem user".

If/when people complain, I ask them to justify their use case. I deal in heavy mail volume environments, but the average user can get pretty far on 3GB of mail storage.